# C: Stack element overwritten by a function call

Tags: c

I'm doing a school assignment, I've I've run into 2 problems. I have to simulate stacks, with arrays.
My current code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int capacity;
    int * array;
    int size;
} stack_tt;
int pop(stack_tt * stack_p);
void push(stack_tt * stack_p, int value);
int top(stack_tt * stack_p);
stack_tt * newStack(void);
int empty(stack_tt * stack_p);

int main() {
    stack_tt * myStack = newStack();
    push(myStack, 123);
    push(myStack, 99);
    push(myStack, 4444);
    while (!empty(myStack)) {
        int value;
        value = pop(myStack);
        printf("popped: %d\n", value);
    }
    return 0; }

stack_tt * newStack(){
    stack_tt * newS = malloc(sizeof(stack_tt) * 20);
    (*newS).capacity = 1;
    (*newS).size = 0;
    return newS;
}

void push(stack_tt * stack_p, int value){
    if ((*stack_p).size >= (*stack_p).capacity) {
        (*stack_p).capacity*=2;
        //realloc(stack_p, stack_p->capacity * sizeof(stack_tt));
    }
    (*stack_p).array = &value;
    (*stack_p).size++;
}

int pop(stack_tt * stack_p){
    (*stack_p).size--;
    int fap = *(*stack_p).array;
    return fap;
}

int empty(stack_tt * stack_p){
    if ((*stack_p).size >= 1)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Fist of, when I call the line 
    while(!empty(myStack))
It changes the value in my array to 1.

secondly I'm not able to change individual values in my array, whenever I try things like:
    (*stack_p).array[0] = value;
It doesn't know where in the memory to look.
I hope someone is able to help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the code as I see it.

Lets take the `push` function where you do

```
(*stack_p).array = &value;
```

That will make the `array` structure member point to the *local* variable `value`, and once the function returns the variable cease to exist leaving you with a stray pointer and using that pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The second problem with that code is that your stack will only be pointing (illegally) to the last element added.

You must allocate memory explicitly for `array` and use `capacity` to keep track of how much memory is allocated. The use `size` as an index into the allocated array for the pushing and popping. Something like

```
stack_tt * newStack(){
    stack_tt * newS = malloc(sizeof(stack_tt));  // Only allocate *one* structure
    newS->capacity = 0;  // Start with zero capacity
    newS->size = 0;
    newS->array = NULL;
    return newS;
}

void push(stack_tt * stack_p, int value){
    if (stack_p->size + 1 > stack_p->capacity){
        // Increase capacity by ten elements
        int new_capacity = stack_p->capacity + 10;
        int * temp_array = realloc(stack_p->array, new_capacity * sizeof(int));
        if (temp_srray == NULL)
            return;

        stack_p->capacity = new_capacity;
        stack_p->array = temp_array;
    }

    stack_p->array[stack_p->size++] = value;
}

int pop(stack_tt * stack_p){
    if (stack_p->size > 0)
        return stack_p->array[--stack_p->size];
    return 0;
}

int empty(stack_tt * stack_p){
    return stack_p->size == 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you please be so kind to accept the following edit in `int pop()`: `if (stack_p->size > 0)`. Else it keeps hanging in infinite loop `popped:0`. I don't have enough rep to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to allocate space for 20 structs of type `stack_tt`, you only need to allocate space for one:

```
stack_tt * newS = malloc(sizeof(stack_tt));
```

however you need to allocate space for elements of the struct member array:

```
newS->array = malloc( sizeof(int)*20);
newS->size = 0;
newS->capacity = 20;
```

now you can use the array member.

---

When you push a value to the 'stack', you shouldn't overwrite the array member with the address of the local variable, that doesn't make sense and will cause undefined behavior in addition of loosing the previously allocated memory. Instead simply assign the value to the member `array`, in the function `push`:

```
stack_p->array[stack_p->size] = value;
stack_p->size++;
```

---

Similarly when you pop an element, take the current element from the member `array`:

```
stack_p->size--;
int fap = stack_p->array[stack_p->size];
```

The rest of the functions and code should be fixed in the same manner.

Comment: I've tried this, I gives me the error: 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x0)'

Comment: @Klopper Of course,  the examples I pointed out are not the only problems. It is not possible to point out every error because the code is wrong on a conceptual level. The whole project will have to be rewritten. Use the examples I have given as a guide.

Comment: Thank you, I see now :)
This was a great help!

Answer (score 0):

You're code is good, but probably you didn't understand the usage of `realloc`:

```
//realloc(stack_p, stack_p->capacity * sizeof(stack_tt));
```

> This function returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, or NULL if the request fails.

The  `realloc` (as the function suggests) takes the memory pointed by the pointer you pass, and **copies** that memory block in a new and resized block. So the right code should be.

```
stack_p->array = realloc(stack_p->array, stack_p->capacity * sizeof(stack_tt));
```

This other line is wrong:

```
(*stack_p).array = &value;
```

Change it with:

```
stack_p->array[stack_p->size] = value;
```

Another little suggestion, every `(*stack_p).` can be replaced by `stack_p->`, which is more elegant.

In the `newStack()` you're `malloc`ing 20 structs which is kinda useless. You just need one.

Then you should `malloc` the array for the first time:

```
newS->array = malloc(sizeof(int));
newS->capacity = 1;
```

Comment: What's wrong with `(*stack_p).` and why should he use `stack_p->` ? What is the benefit of the last one?

Comment: It's just a more elegant code. Elegant code == more readable code and easy to understand

Comment: When pointers are involved there are no differences between elegant and more readable. Just how you understand them.